# Powershell with elevated permissions through RunOnce

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to run a powershell script using the RunOnce registry key.  I need it to run as administrator and I can get the script to run but I can't get it to run with elevated permissions.  Here is what I have tried but it doesn't do anything.

My code:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -verb runas -File c:\script.ps1
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You may have better luck at ServerFault.  I would look at a logon triggered scheduled task. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx)

Comment: The script sets the execution policy to unrestricted but it gives an error saying the registry key that controls the Execution Policy is denied.  If I run the script as admin it works just fine.  As for the logon triggered scheduled task, this is for imaging computers and I would like it to do this at initial logon after getting imaged with Windows 7.  Would the logon triggered scheduled task be more efficient for this?

Comment: Have you tried using the execution policy parameter of powershell.exe?  That will override the execution policy set in the registry and allow the script to run.

Comment: I can't say that I have tried that.  At this point I have created a scheduled task to run at logon and added an If then else statement to make sure it only runs once.

Here is my code -
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$name = (Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber.Trim()
$oldname = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Name.Trim()
IF ($oldname -eq $name){Exit}
Else{ Rename-computer -ComputerName $oldname  -NewName "$name" -force
Start-Sleep -s 5

Restart-Computer}

Comment: After putting in the if else statement the script no longer works, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file .....` and remove the `set-excecution unrestricted` line in your script as it won't have any effect. If powershell is able to read that command in your script file, then it means the script is allowed => execution-policy doesn't need to be changed.

`Set-ExecutionPolicy` is an interactive command, it does not belong in a script(unless running on a remote computer maybe).

Also, if you're trying to execute it with RunOnce, then make sure it's run using the HKLM RunOnce key to make sure it runs in the SYSTEM context(so it has the proper permissions).

Comment: This did not work for me, though in addition I:
* used HKLM instead of HKCU
* disabled the UAC
* logged on with an administrator account